# avoid rounding in SalesPrice

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, ax

When setting trade agreament price to 12.8888, the unit price used in Sales Line is 12.8900. what should I do to avoid this rounding?

Answer (score 2):

On the `PriceDiscTable` form set the `NoOfDecimals` property of the `PriceDiscTable_Amount` control to 4.

Note that there are many places in the code where that amount will get rounded to the roundoff setting for the currency. You can change that rounding for the entire application under General ledger/Setup/Exchange rates on the Round-off tab.

Answer (score 0):

In the Price List form, under Details, click Price List Items, and then click Add Price List Item, then change the Rounding Policy.

Answer (score 0):

Set price to 1288.88 per 100 items.